# ISTQB (Foundation Level) question on V-Model

Tags: istqb

I have seen the following two questions and answers on V-Model in ISTQB Foundation Level Sample questions.

Question 1 - [Source](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/istqb-foundation-level-exam-sample-paper-i/)

- 18) Which of the following is true of the V-model?

  - a) It states that modules are tested against user requirements.
  - b) It only models the testing phase.
  - c) It specifies the test techniques to be used.
  - d) It includes the verification of designs.

Answer

```
- d) It includes the verification of designs.
```

Question 2 - [Source](http://istqbquestionbank.blogspot.se/2012/01/istqb-foundation-sample-question-paper_290.html)

- 26) Which of the following is true of V-model?

  - A. It includes the verification of designs.
  - B. It states that modules are tested against user requirements.
  - C. It specifies the test techniques to be used.
  - D. It only models the testing phase.

Answer

```
- B. It states that modules are tested against user requirements.
```

I'm in confusion as to what is the correct answer. The syllubus (Page 22 of the 2011 Version) says the following about V-Model:

> Software work products (such as business scenarios or use cases, requirements specifications, design documents and code) produced during development are often the basis of testing in one or more test levels

AND

> Verification and validation can be carried out during the development of the software work products.

As per my understanding, both the following answers are correct based on the definition given by ISTQB Foundation Level Syllabus.

- It states that modules are tested against user requirements.
- It includes the verification of designs.

However, the above two questions and the answers given for them are in contradiction to my understanding. Can someone please help me understand what is the basis for the above two answers given by the specific sites

Comment: As per my understanding , I think Both answer are correct. ISTQB has last authority to select which answer is true.

Comment: @Sagar007 Thanks for the reply! I'm on the same page with you

Comment: I had similar concerns albeit for a different question from ISTQB. An expert that was preparing our team (and other teams for a number of years for ISTQB exam) said he does not know why a given answer is the right one, it makes no sense to him as well but we need to learn it by heart. Testing to me is always an open discussion and should be context-based.

Comment: @dzieciou Thanks for the comment. All these comments make me think that some questions in ISTQB are just meant to be by-hearted which is pathetic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me, "It includes the verification of designs." is the correct answer to this question.

As this is the main advantage of using the V model in software development life cycle. Verification and Validation goes along through out the multiple stages.

The other answer, which you mentioned above is applicable for all kind of software development life cycles. User requirements are the bible for all Testing activities irrespective of what kind of model you are using. You always test the modules against the user requirement.

Comment: You sound reasonable enough to believe that the major advantage of V Model is the verification and/or validation. Let us see what others think

Answer (score 2):

I think the real problem is how ISTQB run their certification programme.

They have a predetermined pass/fail rate for their courses (I think 2/3 pass rate). Because the content itself is straightforward, they ensure a certain percentage of applicants fail by making the questions vague and confusing.

That's immoral in my view, and I don't put any weight on whether a person is ISTQB certified or not.

Comment: Do you have any proof of the claim that the ISTQB have a predetermined pass/fail rate? This claim is made about many exams in a variety of fields (I heard it many times about the UK driving test back when I was learning to drive, for example) but without evidence it's difficult to tell whether such claims are true or just a conclusion jumped to by candidates disgruntled at the exam.

Comment: No incontrovertible proof, other than working with guy who was on the ISTQB board (or something) and told me that's how it worked at that time (going back 5 years now).